# Não estou compreendendo esse erro

Tags: php, sql-insert

Meu código PHP:

```
<?php

include "conectar.php";


//comando para iserir dados direto do formulário para o banco de dados

$vnome=$_POST['nome'];
$vcpf=$_POST['cpf'];
$videntidade=$_POST["identidade"];
$vtelefone=$_POST["telefone"];
$vcelular=$_POST["celular"];
$vemail=$_POST["email"];
$vcep=$_POST["cep"];
$vendereco=$_POST["endereco"];
$vcomplemento=$_POST["complemento"];
$vbairro=$_POST["bairro"];
$vcidade=$_POST["cidade"];
$vuf=$_POST["uf"];
$vsexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$vidade=$_POST["idade"];
$vpeso=$_POST["peso"];

$sql="INSERT INTO solidario VALUES ('$vnome', '$vcpf', '$videntidade', '$vtelefone', '$vcelular', '$vemail', '$vcep', '$vendereco', '$vcomplemento', '$vbairro', '$vcidade', '$vuf', '$vsexo', '$vidade', '$vpeso')";

$dependente1=$_POST['dependente1'];
$cpfdependente1=$_POST['cpfdependente1'];
$enderecodependente1=$_POST['enderecodependente1'];
$ufdependente1=$_POST['ufdependente1'];
$sexodependnte1=$_POST['sexodependnte1'];
$idadedependente1=$_POST['idadedependente1'];
$pesodependente1=$_POST['pesodependente1'];

$sqla="INSERT INTO dependente1 VALUES ('$dependente1', '$cpfdependente1', '$ufdependente1', '$enderecodependente1', '$sexodependnte1', '$idadedependente1', '$pesodependente1')";


$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql,$sqla) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$num=mysqli_affected_rows($con);

if($num == 1){
```

E o erro que está dando:

> Aviso : mysqli_query () espera que o parâmetro 3 seja inteiro, seqüência dada em C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ solidario \ insert.php na linha 37

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se tem um arquivo chamando a conexão com o banco de dados, por via das dúvidas eu criei um arquivo `.php` com o nome `conn.php` e você deve colocar o mesmo nome para que o código abaixo funcione corretamente, ou se já tiver um arquivo fazendo isto, troque o nome do:

```
include("conn.php");
```

Para

```
include("insiranomedoseuarquivo.php");
```

conn.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; /*nome do servidor, geralmente localhost funciona*/
$username = "root"; /* O nome do usuário do seu banco de dados */
$password = "senha "; /* A senha do usuário do banco de dados, se não tiver deixe => 
=> $password = "" */
$dbname = "exemplo"; /* O nome do banco a qual voce esta trabalhando */ 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Adicione dentro dos seus `inputs` os `v` na frente dos names.

Exemplo para input do campo nome `<input name='vnome'` e adicione esse código abaixo para inserir os dados, lembrando que para `UPDATE` funcionar deve ter o campo id na sua tabela caso contrário adicione o campo chave no lugar do `id = '$id'`

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

$vnome = $_POST['vnome']; 
$vcpf = $_POST['vcpf']; 
$videntidade = $_POST["videntidade"]; 
$vtelefone = $_POST["vtelefone"]; 
$vcelular = $_POST["vcelular"]; 
$vemail = $_POST["vemail"]; 
$vcep = $_POST["vcep"]; 
$vendereco = $_POST["vendereco"]; 
$vcomplemento = $_POST["vcomplemento"]; 
$vbairro = $_POST["vbairro"]; 
$vcidade=$_POST["vcidade"]; 
$vuf=$_POST["vuf"]; 
$vsexo=$_POST["vsexo"]; 
$vidade=$_POST["vidade"]; 
$vpeso=$_POST["vpeso"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM solidario";
$resulta = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $resulta->fetch_assoc(); 

if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {
    $result_solidario = "UPDATE solidario SET vnome = '$vnome', vcpf = '$vcpf', videntidade = '$videntidade', vtelefone = '$vtelefone', vcelular = '$vcelular, vemail = '$vemail', vcep = '$vcep', vendereco = '$vendereco', vcomplemento = '$vcomplemento', vbairro = '$vbairro', vcidade = '$vcidade', vuf = '$vuf', vsexo = '$vsexo', vidade = '$vidade', vpeso = '$vpeso' WHERE id = '$id' ";
} else {
    $result_solidario = "INSERT INTO solitario (vnome, vcpf, videntidade, vtelefone, vcelular, vemail, vcep, vendereco, vcomplemento, vbairro, vcidade, vuf, vsexo, vidade, vpeso) VALUES ('$vnome', '$vcpf', '$videntidade', '$vtelefone', '$vcelular', '$vemail', '$vcep', '$vendereco', '$vcomplemento', '$vbairro', '$vcidade', '$vuf', '$vsexo', '$vidade', '$vpeso')";
}

$resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_solidario);
echo "$result_solidario <br>";
```

Faça isso para inserir dados na tabela `solitario` e replique para utilizar para outra tabela, e também  repita o comando *INSERT* sempre desta forma como mostrei, deve informar onde irá inserir os campos vindos do formulário e depois quais variáveis irão ser responsáveis para inserir dados nestes campos da tabela que você indicou.

E repare que o `mysqli_query` só pode receber dois parâmetros, e eu indiquei a variável utilizada para criar a conexão com o banco de dados no arquivo `conn.php` e a variável responsável por receber o comando `insert`.

Desta forma os registros serão inseridos.

Comment: obrigado Victor! Tentarei e direi o resultado!

Comment: Ok, estarei aqui caso aconteca algo, edite o código e o erro e faz um comentario para eu ficar alertado e vir resolver